# How to configure Email in Magento2.0.7?

Tags: magento2, transactional-mail, magento-2.0.7, crontab

I have set cron job but any **emails are not send**.

Below is my crontab. It is running but emails are not send.

Suggest me some solution.

```
*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/php -c /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini /var/www/magento2/bin/magento cron:run > /var/www/magento2/var/log/magento.cron.log&

*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/php -c /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini /var/www/magento2/update/cron.php > /var/www/magento2/var/log/update.cron.log&

*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/php -c /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini /var/www/magento2/bin/magento setup:cron:run > /var/www/magento2/var/log/setup.cron.log&
```

Comment: Do you have install smtp email extension ?

Comment: @S H Patel No I did not install smtp email extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento-2 configure below extension for send email.

[Gmail Smtp App for Magento2](https://github.com/magepal/magento2-gmailsmtpapp)